# How to create Buffergeometry for contiguous triangles

Tags: three.js

I have, for example, 2 contiguous triangles. I'd need 4 points to define the vertices.
For 3 I'd need 5 points and so on.
Using bufferGeometry to create the object gives me 6 points for two triangles, 9 points for   3 triangles, etc. 
In case of 10000 triangles I have a lot of points duplicated. I spent more memory than neccesary. Of course I know I need independent normals and colors data for every triangle, but the coords for points could be shared.

Is there any way to solve this problem ? 
In adition, how to label every triangle ? I need to know what triangle I have picked.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The method you're describing is "triangle strips". If you google for that you'll find a lot of existing three.js issues, e.g. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2523 :)

Further you can build up the buffer geometry on your own. If you want to use triangle strips they have to be in the right order anyway, and you best do that if you create the positions by yourself.

Comment: mmmm I'd need more help. The link provided does not give me information.... I'm using a bufferGeometry... and I dont know how to implement a trianglestrip here, Can I ?

Comment: It doesn't? They tell you there that you can, and that it might make sense for meshes with a "single continuous strip of triangles", i.e. in some instances you could build up the mesh with triangle strips (e.g. a sphere. If you peel an apple you can somehow have the triangle strip there :) ). But if you have to make two draw calls instead of one the performance benefit is already lost. Because of that, and because building a mesh with triangle strips is hard to apply, most 3d engines don't make a broad use of it... (And for the exact way on how to implement it I'd read up on triangle strips).